# Call function with params as another functions param

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

this has been bugging me, and I'd like to understand. 
Let's say that I have a site, where some elements need to be switched at a certain window size. So I've created a function that I can call with any elements.

```
function switcher (one, two) {
  if (win.width() < 900) {
    one.insertAfter(two);
  } else {
    one.insertBefore(two);
  }
}

var frst = div.find('.first');
var scnd = div.find('.second');
```

**My question is**: this is working:

```
win.on('resize', function () {
  switcher(frst, scnd);
});
```

this is NOT working, and WHY?

```
win.on('resize', switcher(frst, scnd));
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to pass the function to `on`, not call the function. `win.on('resize', () => switcher(frst, scnd));` or bind

Comment: The latter doesn't work because you're calling the `switcher()` function and assigning the *result* of the call to the `resize` event handler. You instead need to provide a function *reference*. Also note that style switching based on window size should be done in CSS, not JS.

Comment: Be aware that arrow functions, as in @CertainPerformance's answer, are not supported at all in IE

Comment: another way: `win.on('resize', switcher.bind(null, frst, scnd));`